How to use Zod with @supabase/srr in NextJs
I'm trying to authenticate using @supabase/srr.
In the docs the login/signup form is supposed to be a server component as it calls login and signup servers actions
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/server-side/nextjs
import { login, signup } from './actions'

export default function LoginPage() {
  return (
    <form>
      <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
      <input id="email" name="email" type="email" required />
      <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
      <input id="password" name="password" type="password" required />
      <button formAction={login}>Log in</button>
      <button formAction={signup}>Sign up</button>
    </form>
  )
}

I want to use zod for this form, but the useForm hook (from react-hook-form) is obviously client side and I'm also using some stateful values.
So what is good practice here ? Is it just not a problem to call my actions from a client component ?
or should I make my actions api endpoints ? or any other solutions ?

call server action from client component is common practice. you can pass formdata to server action and than validate it on server side. i will provide two common way. first will be using ssr and second using client side
1.call login action from ssr component
import { z } from "zod";

const loginSchema = z.object({
  email: z.string().email("Invalid email format"),
  password: z.string().min(6, "Password must be at least 6 characters long"),
});

export default function LoginPage() {
  async function login(formData: FormData) {
    'use server';
    const rawFormData = {
      email: formData.get("email"),
      password: formData.get("password")
    };

    // Validate data
    const result = loginSchema.safeParse(rawFormData);
    if (!result.success) {
      // Handle validation errors
      return;
    }
    const validatedData = result.data;
    // Proceed with login logic using validatedData
  }

  return (
    <form action={login}>
      <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
      <input id="email" name="email" type="email" required />
      <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
      <input id="password" name="password" type="password" required />
      <button formAction={login}>Log in</button>
    </form>
  );
}

2.call login action from client side (also normal, common and safe way)
"use client";
import { login } from "@/components/actions";

export default function LoginPage() {
  async function handleSubmit(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);

    try {
      await login(formData);
      console.log("Login successful");
      // Redirect or update the UI on success
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Login failed:", error);
      // Display error message in the UI
    }
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
      <input id="email" name="email" type="email" required />
      <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
      <input id="password" name="password" type="password" required />
      <button type="submit">Log in</button>
    </form>
  );
}

